# How to create database duing C# application installation

Tags: c#, database, installation

I have developed a Windows application using C# .NET. I made an installer using Visual studio setup project.

If I install it in another computer I have to separately create database with all required table.

Considering users convenience, I need to integrate all this tasks to a single installer and left no hard work end user.

Answer (score 1):

Normally database should be at database server and your application should connect to it but if it's not possible you can use embeded versions of databases. You can embed your configured database to your application. Using embeded databases can increase size of your setup file because they install a small database server to end-user's pc.